# How to shield a javascript string in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, php-5.3

I have a problem with my javascript string in php. So I tried to add a string to a variable in switch but I get error :

```
$blocPub = '<script type="text/javascript">
          var rdads=new String(Math.random()).substring (2, 11);
          document.write('<sc'+'ript type="text/javascript" src="http://test.com?sdsds?bhhj'+rdads+'dsdsdsdsds"></sc'+'ript>');
            </script>';
```

The error is in document.write. Exist a method to ecranate this string? Please help me!! Thx in advance.

Comment: He mean escape i suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes inside quote.

```
$blocPub = '<script type="text/javascript">var rdads = new String(Math.random()).substring(2, 11);document.write(\'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.com?sdsds?bhhjbf=fdfdfd"></script>\'); </script>';
```

Comment: There exist a concatenation in src..How to escape this?Thx

Answer (score 0):

See if below works. You can either escape strings or alternate between "(double) and '(single) or do both in your case

```
case 7 :
        $blocPub = '<script type="text/javascript">
                        var rdads=new String(Math.random()).substring (2, 11);
                        document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://test.com?sdsds?bhhjbf=fdfdfd\"></script>");
                    </script>';
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$blocPub = '<script type="text/javascript">
                        var rdads=new String(Math.random()).substring (2, 11);
                        document.write("<sc"+"ript type=\"text/javascript\" src="http://test.com?sdsds?bhhjbf=fdfdfd"></sc"+"ript>");
                    </script>';
```

Try this, i think you have mistake with quotes

Comment: There exist a concatenation in src..How to escape this?Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
$blocPub = '<script type="text/javascript">
                        var rdads=new String(Math.random()).substring (2, 11);
                        document.write("<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.com?sdsds?bhhjbf=fdfdfd"/>");
                    </script>';
```

Comment: There exist a concatenation in src..How to escape this?Thx

Comment: what do you want to achive from this variable?